# Pyppeteer code gives error after executing

Tags: python, python-asyncio, pyppeteer

so I've saw an example code of pyppeteer and tried to execute it and it gave me this error:

"Exception has occurred: OSError
[WinError 14001] The application has failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect. Please see the application event log or use the command-line sxstrace.exe tool for more detail"

Here is the code:

```
import asyncio
from pyppeteer import launch

async def main():
    browser = await launch()
    page = await browser.newPage()
    await page.goto('http://example.com')
    await page.screenshot({'path': 'example.png'})
    await browser.close()

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
```

I've searched online to see if I can fix it but none of the results could fix my problem.

Here is a screenshot of the error:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/2CZ4r.jpg

Sorry for my bad grammer.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so instead of using pyppeteer I've used playwright and it works perfectly.